# Is it a good way to hit laravel api every second?

Tags: laravel, react-native, axios

I am using `react native` with `laravel backend` .So in react native I created a messenger screen where user can send and receives messages from other users for that firstly I get all messages in `ComponentDidMount` and show these messages in my `View`. And If user send any message I send It to `laravel` with `axios`.And to make chat screen up to date I done that

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._retrieveData()
  this.interval = setInterval(() => this._retrieveMessages(), 5000);
}
```

So That If Any New message received I will update the chat screen.
So Basically My question is that weather it affect the working of my react native app because I hit `laravel api` after every 5 seconds?

Comment: It is better to use a websocket for this usecase. You can read more about it in the official documentation.

Comment: This is called "short polling". It's a bit wasteful compared to the alternatives (long polling or websockets), but it's easy to implement.

Comment: when it is easy to implement then why it is wasteful?

Comment: what you save in developer time, you pay back in server costs.

Comment: that's gonna stress your server

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine there are a developer and a client, the dev doing a project for the client and the client wants every update about the project okay?

#### Case one

what happens if the client every 5-sec calls the dev and asks if there is something new? I think the dev will delay at something like answering the client or finishing the project.

#### Case two

The dev calls the client if anything is updated.

Which one is better?

Let's back to your case, Let's imagine a user left the app running so the app will take the server's resources for nothing. What about 1000 users?

So what is the better scenario? it is using "realtime web application" like `websockets` or `socket io`. What's happening with `websockets` or `socket io`? If user_1 sends a message the server will send the message to user_2, meaning the user_2 will wait for any updates, won't ask the server every 5-sec.

If you use a "real-time web application", the cost of the server will be lower and more stable.

[Understand What's Behind Real-Time Web Apps](https://medium.com/geekculture/understand-whats-behind-real-time-web-apps-e60168129480)

---

I hope I was clear.

If anything wrong I said, I hope someone tells me.